# How exactly Heredoc handles curly braces?

Tags: php, html, image

I was using the PHP Heredoc and found something that was a bit confusing for me, maybe a bug or maybe I'm just a rookie.

So here is what confusing for me:

```
echo <<<TEXT
         <img src="images/achivements/{$achievement_id}.png" alt="{$achievementName}">
     TEXT;
```

I thought this would return something like:

> `<img src="images/achivements/idOfAchievement.png" alt="nameOfTheAchievement">`

but it returns:

> `<img src="images/achivements/{idOfAchievement}.png" alt="nameOfTheAchievement">`

It leaves the curly braces inside the `src=""` and removes it at the `alt=""`

So a solution would be something like this:

```
echo <<<TEXT
         <img src="images/achivements/$achievement_id.png" alt="{$achievementName}">
     TEXT;
```

Is there an explanation why it works like this?

Thank you for reading this and have a good day!

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? [demo](https://3v4l.org/nSg1X) - no curly braces...

Comment: @jibsteroos I'm using version 8.0.7

Comment: [odd](https://3v4l.org/nSg1X#v8.0.7)

Comment: Oh I found the problem. Using backslash breaks it! [code](https://3v4l.org/pM2QL)

Comment: Always make sure you test that the example you're posting is a [mcve] - in this case, it didn't reproduce the problem, so we had no way of guessing the real issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using backslash like:

```
echo <<<TEXT
        <img src="images\achivements\{$achievement_id}.png" alt="{$achievementName}">
     TEXT;
```

returns:
[Image from inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WAKv.png)

And this:

```
echo <<<TEXT
       <img src="images/achivements/{$achievement_id}.png" alt="{$achievementName}">
     TEXT;
```

returns: [Image from inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzXUq.png)

Comment: Yes, backslash is used to "escape" characters when you *don't* want them to have special meaning. To escape the backslash, add another backslash (but also, don't use backslashes in URLs).